# in slime-autodoc: error in process filter: Wrong type argument: sequencep, :not-available

Tags: emacs, slime, autodoc

When I use the slime-repl, I get this message in my minibuffer and emacs hangs for a second:

error in process filter: Wrong type argument: sequencep, :not-available

It stops happening when I turn off slime-autodoc-mode

Has anyone seen that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this error report](https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js/issues/40)

> **joddie commented:**
>   I experienced the same problem. After a cursory
>   investigation, it seems to be related to enabling the slime-fancy
>   module in slime/contrib. slime-fancy is a shortcut for enabling a
>   number of different slime modules, and I'm not sure which one is the
>   actual source of the problem, but disabling it seems to fix the
>   problem here at least.
>
> (This is using the latest Git/CVS versions of slime and slime-js,
>   although I also tried rolling back to the 2010-02-12 version of slime
>   just in case; it made no difference).
>
> **ghost commented:**  @joddie : I just try it and remove slime-fancy, it
>   does work. Now I put
>
> (slime-setup '(slime-js slime-repl))
>
> in my .emacs. Before that I can not use auto complete in node even my
>   tab already bound to slime-indent-and-complete-symbol. Thanks. :)

For those of you using quicklisp and slime-helper to manage their slime setup open quicklisp/slime-helper.el to find the place where **(slime-setup)** is used.